# get last part of page url and add it as cat in wp_query

Tags: functions, wp-query, filters

I have a page URL : https://mwallpaper.ir/mobile-wallpapers/birds

and I grabbed last part of URL with this filter :

```
add_filter( 'example_filter', 'catslug_callback' );
function catslug_callback( $cat_slug ) {
    preg_match("/[^\/]+$/", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], $matches);
    $cat_slug = $matches[0];
    return $cat_slug;
}
```

and also have a query (for some reason in functions.php) to grab attachments from posts of a certain category, that query should get last part of url as category of posts.
this is function for that query :

```
function my_wallpaper_listing( $args, $id ){
    $last_word = apply_filters( 'example_filter', '' );
    $query = new WP_Query( 
    array(
        'category_name' => $last_word,
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'fields' => 'ids'
    ));
    $args['post_type'] = 'attachment';
    $args['post_status'] = 'any';
    $args['post_parent__in'] = $query->posts;
    return $args;
}
add_filter( 'alm_query_args_wallpaper_listing', 'my_wallpaper_listing', 10, 2);
```

but this loads all attachments of all posts, and doesn't filter by category.

if I change `'category_name' => $last_word,` to `'category_name' => 'birds',` its worked, But this function needs to work dynamically (get last part of url as category).